# How to make sure a flex item is affected by its children's width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following flex and it's children (img):

[image]

```
<div class="flex">
  <img>
</div>

.flex {
  position: relative
  -webkit-box-pack: center!important
  display: flex!important
  box-sizing: inherit
}

img {
  max-height: 124px
  height: 100%
  vertical-align: middle
  box-sizing: inherit
}
```

Sometimes `.flex` doesn't have width ... other times it has.

How to make sure .flex always have the children's width? (In this case that of an image?)

Comment: How should the image behave when `.flex` has a width? ... stretch, always keep width/aspect ratio and be clipped at top/bottom, ...? ... If you could provide 2 samples showing when `.flex` has and has not a width, and the wanted output in each case

Comment: Please review and comment on any answer, and let us know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: @LGSon Well, it didnt' work in the end. The width still disappears from time to time. Ha.

Comment: If you can show a use case where it still happens, I'm sure we can help you find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content), which one set as the parents `width`, lack reasonable browser support, use `inline-flex`.

```css
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  align-items: center;         /*  vert. align img  */
}

.flex img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 124px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x350/">
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x50/">
</div>
```

---

*Note, because of inconsistency between the browsers, an `img` as a flex item might render differently and a wrapper normally fixes that.*

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is to apply **[`width: fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content)** to the flex element.

Without this, `.flex` in the following example will stretch to the edge of the container.
With this, `.flex` only stretches as wide as the content contained within (in this case, the image):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)